# C++ pass by reference tricky situation

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to figure what happens to an "rvalue",temporary object, after the variable used to refer this object deleted from stack.

Code example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
  private:
  int &ref;
  public:
  Base(int &passed):ref(passed)
  {
    cout << "Value is " << ref << endl;
  }
  int getvalue(){
    return ref;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Base *myobject;
    {
    int ref=10;
    myobject = new Base (ref);
    ref++;
    }                           //ref delete from stack. 
  cout << myobject->getvalue() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I expected the second output(second cout) to give me some random garbage because ref deleted but instead I got the value of the current state of ref, I wander what happened after the ref got deleted is it pure luck? or myobject.ref stored the value of the ref he construct with?

Edit: adding a visualizer to support my point that in the end myobject.ref pointing nowhere [C++ visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/cpp.html#code=%23include%3Ciostream%3E%0Ausing%20namespace%20std%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Base%0A%7B%0A%20%20private%3A%0A%20%20int%20%26ref%3B%0A%20%20public%3A%0A%20%20Base%28int%20%26passed%29%3Aref%28passed%29%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20cout%20%3C%3C%20%22Value%20is%20%22%20%3C%3C%20ref%20%3C%3C%20endl%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20int%20getvalue%28%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20ref%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint%20main%28%29%0A%7B%0A%20%20Base%20*myobject%3B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20int%20ref%3D10%3B%0A%20%20myobject%20%3D%20new%20Base%20%28ref%29%3B%0A%20%20ref%2B%2B%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20cout%20%3C%3C%20myobject-%3Egetvalue%28%29%3B%0A%20%20return%200%3B%0A%7D&curInstr=12&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=cpp_g%2B%2B9.3.0&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)

Comment: Old value is a possible value of garbage... anyway, reading dangling reference/pointer is UB.

Comment: It's basically luck. It is an error in C++ to assume that all programming errors will produce an obvious diagnoseable state. Often, it results in a state that looks an awful lot like it works, only producing undesired behavior much later in a seemingly unrelated part of the code.

Comment: The C++ standard does not require a variable to be overwritten with "garbage" as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: Combining Undefined Behavior with _"I expected..."_ suggests a misunderstanding of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: These tests to see "what happens if I do something wrong" many times winds up with the compiler eliminating the nonsense code under optimization.  For example `if (this == nullptr) { ... }`  is a nonsense test, and the compiler is free to eliminate that `if` statement, plus any block of code associated with that `if` statement being `true`.  So if the compiler detects that you are doing something that could never work, don't be surprised if the compiler's optimizer eliminates such code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you

Comment: the 11 output is "garbage". Suppose you are writing a program for multiplication and confuse `+` with `*` then the program is garbage, even though you get seemingly correct output in some cases (eg `2+2 == 2*2`). Though it isnt random by any means. If you study the output of the compiler you can know why you get the output you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Reference declaration documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Dangling_references#Dangling_references)

> it is possible to create a program where the lifetime of the referred-to object ends, but the reference remains accessible (**dangling**). Accessing such a reference is **undefined behavior**.

In your program the referred-to object `ref` ends at `}` after `ref++`. This means that the `ref` data member is now a **dangling reference**. And according to the above quoted statement, accessing that reference(which you do when you call `getValue`) is **undefiend behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. For example, the output of the same program is different [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZTWZ7TaQ2iHum5Do) and [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NdXcuJ8AawvSvI3F).

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> is it pure luck?

Yes. The lifetime of the object to which the reference refers ends at the `}` after `ref++;`.

Trying to read the value of the object after that causes undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that you have no guarantee how the program will behave, which includes the possibility of it seemingly working, but another run or compilation of the program may give you a different result.

Practically speaking, destroying a `int` object doesn't require the execution of any machine instructions and if the object has space allocated on the function's stack, there is a good possibility that the value will just be read from the location where the `int` object was located, with whatever value it had last. The compiler does not need to overwrite it.

But you can see undefined behavior in action if you compile with optimizations enabled. For example GCC 11.2 with `-O2` on x86_64 produces the output

```
Value is 10
10
```

but without optimization flags it produces

```
Value is 10
11
```

(see https://godbolt.org/z/EqKG83c18).

But undefined behavior doesn't just mean that the value printed will be unspecified. The whole program has no behavior guarantees and it could also output nothing or garbage text or anything else.

Comment: Well that's the reason I love overflow, thank you.